# Vim frozen and unresponsive on startup

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, zsh, vi

I am using zsh on macOS. When I type `vim`, it opens, but it is completely frozen:

[image]

Anything I press on the keyboard does not display or change the window. In order to exit, I have to terminate the terminal session.

I *did* recently uninstall Homebrew, so it could be that this corrupted the program.

Does anyone know how this can be fixed? Is there a way to reinstall or update the system Vim (preferably, *without* Homebrew – it causes more problems than it solves).

Comment: OP didn’t realize migration of this was possible. Thanks for the collaboration to get an answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/63460546/6828329

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `vim` starts, it reads these two files from your home folder:

- `.vimrc`, a configuration file that contains initialization commands
- `.viminfo`, a history file that contains, among others, string and pattern search information

`vim` may become unresponsive if any of these two files are very large or contain corrupt entries.

To prevent `vim` from reading them, either:

1. Rename them:

   ```
    cd ~
    mv .vimrc .vimrc.bak
    mv .viminfo .viminfo.bak
   ```

   where `~` is shorthand for your home folder.

   (Ignore any `No such file or directory` errors, it just means the file doesn't exist.)
2. and start `vim` as usual:

   ```
    vim
   ```

or, alternatively, start `vim` as follows:

```
vim -u NONE -i NONE
```

where the `-u NONE` option tells `vim` not to read `~/.vimrc` and `-i NONE` achieves the same result for `~/.viminfo`.

If `vim` starts normally, you can rename back one file at a time to find the culprit and delete it.

If you want to find out more about the differences between `.vimrc` and `.viminfo`, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/323368). For information on the use of `~`, see the [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) or [Zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion).